# Convert multiple Int64Index([], dtype='int64') in a list to a list

Tags: python, pandas

I have a list with int64index, I want to change it to a flat list. Can you help me with this? here is a simple example.

```
l = [Int64Index([518], dtype='int64'), Int64Index([599], dtype='int64'), Int64Index([614], dtype='int64')]
```

The output:

```
[518, 599, 614]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably *fix* whatever process produced this in the first place, but you can get a `list` of python `int` objects using something like:

```
[x for idx in l for x in idx.tolist()]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`np.ravel`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ravel.html) and `tolist()` to get the flattened python list.

```
np.ravel(l).tolist()
```

If you want pandas Index:

```
pd.Index(np.ravel(l))
```